# CSS to hide element in order to prevent wrapping

Tags: css

Ok, I'm aware of media queries but they are strictly related to a certain width. Sometimes it's not convenient. Say I have bootstrap navbar with logo image and h1 in one line, like here

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <a class="navbar-brand">LOGO</a>
  <h1 class="d-inline">Long enough header</h1>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zzmaster/qno7utp0/2/

On a certain screen width it wraps into two lines. I'd prefer to hide the logo and make this process independent of the width of the second element. Ideally I think of a class of hiding priority like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="prio-1">one</div>
    <div class="prio-2">two</div>
    <div class="prio-3">three</div>
</div>
```

meaning preventing line wrap by hiding less priority-objects. Is it possible?